# tensorflow - inconsistency in training

Tags: tensorflow, keras

I am using tensorflow 2.2.0.  Between yesterday and today, nothing has changed in my training data or model design, but my training step is taking too long to show any decent progress on accuracy/loss. Yesterday, after running 1/10th of the epochs, the accuracy was around 0.3, but today, at this same point, the accuracy is stuck at 0.03.  What could be the reason ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you start the training tensorflow sets the initial values of the weights randomly, that's the reason why the behavior changed. As for why it's stuck at low accuracy, it maybe because the gradient stuck at a local minima [image: local minima]
To make sure it's a local minima increasing the number of epochs and the learning rate, this should solve it. or just run the model again.

Comment: yes, it was probably stuck at local minima.. just a re-run worked !  Thank you !

Answer (score 0):

Your algorithm might be the problem. Try improving it, research more on different algorithms and how they work. Give it more training data too.

Comment: Yesterday it ran till about 1/3rd of the epochs and gave an accuracy of 72%; so I don't think it's an issue with the algorithm.

Comment: It may be the amount of training data that you gave.